# How do I tell which drill kit will be useful and suit best for DIY requirements?

Tags: tools, drill, powertools, hand-tools

I believe [Skil's drill kit](http://www.amazon.in/Skil-6513-Variable-Hammering-Function/dp/B00I9IKEDS/ref=sr_1_4?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1464333424&sr=1-4&keywords=bosch%2013mm%20drill%20machine) works best for electrical and masonry requirements and a smart [hand tool kit](http://www.amazon.in/Skil-Piece-Stubby-Wrench-Black/dp/B00IN1FR8I?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_image_2&smid=A14UQ4H17XUX90) from Skil for almost all plumbing related issues.

These two products make a good combination to do things yourself without relying on professionals for many issues. But an average middle-class guy may hesitate to spend extra on the Hand Tool Kit and worth purchasing as it is very expensive.

One can buy Bosch's 13 mm drill kit (www.amzn.to/1UhdWRE) which has everything, but its drill capacity is lower than Skil's (I don't know why although the chuck size is the same) and almost double the rate of Skil's.

Could anybody help preparing a toolset that covers everything for DYI needs?

Comment: @Tester101, I think this question is specific enough to not cause opinionated answers and also general enough to not become obsolete quickly. Although it does reference specific items, it's more about "does it make sense to pay for a top brand" and "what tool set a beginner DIYer should invest in".

Comment: @Tester101 Sorry for not drafting the question properly. I've edited the question later, could you consider re-opening it so it helps other DYI enthusiasts? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry @IamSJ, I just don't feel that this is a good fit for the site.  The site works best when you ask specific answerable questions. Answers to a question like this will be heavily opinionated, and there's likely to be a ton of short single item type answers. By editing the question, it's automatically moved into the "*Reopen queue*". So other members of the site have the ability to vote to reopen the question.

Comment: I understand, will wait for upvotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternatives that cover everything for DYI needs

1. There is no such thing. Whatever you buy now, you will miss something at some point in your DIY life. It may be less obvious than it looks.

My recent example: I was running a conduit in my garage, and was fixing the clips to the wall with screws. The bits that come with my electric screw driver turned out to be too short and the holder for them too thick to reach the screw cap inside the clips. So I used what you would call a duplicate from my hand-tool set. If the hand-tool bits also were too short/thick, I'd have to buy a set of longer bits. And it's OK.

2. Even if you do compose a complete set, you will probably miss something at some point in the future because your demand will grow power-/comfort-/functionality-wise.

So it's a good idea to buy what seems to cover all your needs today, and be prepared to spend a little extra if and when you need it. It will not be expensive, unless you will need something very special. But you are guaranteed to not spend unnecessary money on what you may never need by building a "complete" set now.

### I've chosen Skil's drill kit and thinking about purchasing a hand tool kit.

What you've found looks very good to me. I have some limited experience with a Skil corded drill/screwdriver, and it was good. Quality/price-wise it's close to the optimum.

You definitely need some hand-tools, and your combined choice looks fine. One thing you'll miss with the Skil set is the water level present in the Bosch set, but it's not worthy paying for the whole Bosch set; just buy it separately. I discovered that my water level (60 cm) is sometimes too short and often too long, so you'll probably need a few of them anyway.

### What your set is missing

Obviously we can spot already now what your set does not include (e.g. for electricity, plumbing, masonry work), but it doesn't mean it's bad. It depends a lot on what work you're going to do, so buy those things once you need them.

One thing you may want to consider soon is a vise. But wait till you need it, since they come in very different sizes, and you cannot buy one for all cases.

Also, get some personal protection items, at the very least glasses and gloves. I didn't use them for years, recently started using them and I love this change.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. 

I wanted to purchase a Vise but couldn't get one from a top brand. Will wait for some time.